# How do we get all columns which are the part of sortkey in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to get all columns, which are the part of sortkey in Redshift.

I tried get information using "select * from svv_table_info" but it have only the information of one column only. Can you let me know, how do I get all columns which are the part of Sortkey for a table.

Thanks,
Sanjeev

Answer (score 5):

Thanks all for your help. I already tried "pg_table_def" table to get sortkey and distkey information but I have seen only pg_catalog and Public schema, I just go through the Amazon developer guide and found we need to add schema to search path using below commands:-
show search_path;
set search_path to '$user', 'public', 'NewSchema';

After adding the "NewSchema" in search path I can see sortkey and distkey information for this schema in pg_table_def

Thanks,
Sanjeev

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
select "column", type, encoding, distkey, sortkey, "notnull" 
from pg_table_def
where tablename = 'YOURTABLE' 
and sortkey <> 0;
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I already tried pg_table_def table to get sortkey and distkey information but I have seen only pg_catalog and Public schema, I just go through the Amazone developer guide and found we need to add schema to search path using below commands.

Answer (score 3):

Sanjeev,

A table called pg_table_def has information about the columns.

In the example below, I created a simple table with four columns and used 2 of these columns as my sort key.

As you can see in my query results the "sort key" field shows a number other than 0 if the column is part of a sort key.

```
dev=# drop table tb1;
DROP TABLE
dev=# create table tb1 (col1 integer, col2 integer, col3 integer, col4 integer) distkey(col1) sortkey(col2, col4);
CREATE TABLE
dev=# select * from pg_table_def where tablename = 'tb1';
 schemaname | tablename | column |  type   | encoding | distkey | sortkey | notnull 
------------+-----------+--------+---------+----------+---------+---------+---------
 public     | tb1       | col1   | integer | none     | t       |       0 | f
 public     | tb1       | col2   | integer | none     | f       |       1 | f
 public     | tb1       | col3   | integer | none     | f       |       0 | f
 public     | tb1       | col4   | integer | none     | f       |       2 | f
(4 rows)
```